# Cannot establish TLS with client

Tags: android, mitmproxy, burp

I have configured android APP to bypass certificate pinning using some modification of app and installed mitm certificate as system and user in android

After running mitmproxy and mitmdump i got below error

however i tried all possible way to solve issue but only in one app i am facing this error

```
Certificate verification error for www.kjljjlk.com.mx:
                          ("hostname 'www.hjkhjk.com.mx' doesn't match either
                          of 'a248.e.jhkhkdsfsf.net', '*.dsfsfds-sdfsdfdsf.net',
                          '*.sdffdsfsdf.net', '*.dsfsdfdsf-sdfsfsf.net',
                          '*.dfsfsdsdf.net'",)
```

```
 << Cannot establish TLS with client (sni: xyxyxyxy.com): TlsException("SSL handshake error: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_client_hello', 'parse tlsext')])")
```

I also try to run with burpsuite, but i get unknown_ca error

After all i tried to open site in firefox, and i get warning of potential risk

> xyxyxyx.com uses an invalid security certificate.   The certificate is
>   not trusted because it is self-signed.   Error code:
>   MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

so i click on accept risk and continue, then it open

but somehow in android app it is not accessing site

any help pls

Thank you

======

```
> Mitmproxy: 5.0.0 binary Python:    3.7.5 OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20
> Nov 2018 Platform: 
> Linux-5.3.0-7625-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
```

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, you can disable certificate checking with the ssl_insecure option.

What TLS versions are supported by the server? It might be that the server is TLS 1.3 only, which mitmproxy doesn't support at the moment (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/pull/3692).

Comment: Okay. I tried with `--ssl-insecure` but still getting same error. Also site has TLS 1.3, so as you told that is not supported yet. any other way to capture?

Comment: Does mitmproxy 6.0.2 not support TLS1.2?

Comment: @Alex: It definitely does, even though you should upgrade to version 7. :)

Comment: Dear @MaximilianHils: tks for u answer

Comment: But my code is not working properly. It looks like you deleted ProxyConfig and ProxyServer. Is there any way to do it?tks.

Comment: I updated the 7.0.2 version and reinstalled the certificate, and the following error occurred: `Client TLS handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for xxx.xxx.xxx  (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert certificate unknown')]))`

Comment: @Alex: What kind of client are you using?

Comment: Android+MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Thanks. I think I can't help you much more beyond the error message. It looks like your client does not trust mitmproxy's certificate, there's not much we can do about this. See https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/#certificate-pinning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237195/discussion-between-alex-and-maximilian-hils).

Comment: @MaximilianHils many thanks!

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? I updated from 4 which was working fine to 7 which no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

@MaximilianHils

```
    from mitmproxy import options
    from mitmproxy import proxy
    from mitmproxy.tools import dump
    
    myaddon = Myaddon()
    prot = sys.argv[1]
    opts = options.Options(listen_port=int(prot), ssl_insecure=True, http2=False)
    pconf = proxy.config.ProxyConfig(opts)
    m = dump.DumpMaster(opts)
    m.server = proxy.server.ProxyServer(pconf)
    m.addons.add(myaddon)
```